# How to edit and change checkout field labels in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, labels

Is there a way that I can edit or change the **State/Province** and **Zip/Postal** Labels to **County** and **Postcode** as I am working on UK based website.

I searched a lot in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/` files and folders but I couldn't get anything where I can **edit** or **change** the labels.

I also tried to change the labels after moving `vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv` file to `app/code/Magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv` and then Clearing the `var/cache` and `var/page_cache` folder, but no success.

Can someone just guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 7):

The best way to implement this is by using translation csv. You can follow below steps:

1) As you are working in UK geography, I am assuming your locale would be set to English(United Kingdom). If not, first change your locale to English(United Kingdom). Alternatively, if you don't want to change it, just note the current locale set in your system.

2) Goto `app\design\frontend\Magento\Themename\i18n`

3) You might find a CSV file there. If you have kept locale as English(United States) which is a default one, there will be a file named `en_US.csv`. If you have changed it to English(United Kingdom), you will have to create a file named `en_GB.csv`

4) You can add any translation in this file along with the current one. Check the screenshot for better clarity.

[image: Translate CSV]

Hope it helps.